# Error while compiling "5.9. Binutils-2.25 - Pass 2 "

Tags: ubuntu, make, lfs

When I try to build binutils, I get the following error

```
make[1]: *** [configure-bfd] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build' 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is the full verbose of the build:

```
lfs@Bee-HD:/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build$ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build'
Configuring in ./intl
configure: creating cache ./config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether NLS is requested... no
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-ranlib... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ranlib
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking how to run the C preprocessor... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C Library 2.1 or newer... yes
checking whether integer division by zero raises SIGFPE... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unsigned long long... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking whether the inttypes.h PRIxNN macros are broken... no
checking for ld used by GCC... /mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking argz.h usability... yes
checking argz.h presence... yes
checking for argz.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking nl_types.h usability... yes
checking nl_types.h presence... yes
checking for nl_types.h... yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for feof_unlocked... yes
checking for fgets_unlocked... yes
checking for getc_unlocked... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for getegid... yes
checking for geteuid... yes
checking for getgid... yes
checking for getuid... yes
checking for mempcpy... yes
checking for munmap... yes
checking for putenv... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for stpcpy... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for tsearch... yes
checking for __argz_count... yes
checking for __argz_stringify... yes
checking for __argz_next... yes
checking for __fsetlocking... yes
checking for iconv... yes
checking for iconv declaration... install-shextern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... yes
checking for LC_MESSAGES... yes
checking for bison... bison
checking version of bison... 3.0.2, ok
checking whether NLS is requested... no
checking whether to use NLS... no
checking for aclocal... aclocal
checking for autoconf... autoconf
checking for autoheader... autoheader
configure: updating cache ./config.cache
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.intl
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing default-1 commands
mkdir -p -- ./libiberty
Configuring in ./libiberty
configure: creating cache ./config.cache
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo --split-size=5000000
checking for perl... perl
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-ar... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ar
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-ranlib... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ranlib
checking whether to install libiberty headers and static library... no
configure: target_header_dir = 
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -E
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc supports -W... yes
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc supports -Wall... yes
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc supports -Wwrite-strings... yes
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc supports -Wc++-compat... yes
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc supports -Wstrict-prototypes... yes
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc supports -pedantic ... yes
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for time.h... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking for sys/pstat.h... no
checking for sys/sysmp.h... no
checking for sys/sysinfo.h... yes
checking for machine/hal_sysinfo.h... no
checking for sys/table.h... no
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking for sys/systemcfg.h... no
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdio_ext.h... yes
checking for process.h... no
checking for sys/prctl.h... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether errno must be declared... no
checking size of int... 4
checking for a 64-bit type... uint64_t
checking for intptr_t... yes
checking for uintptr_t... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for asprintf... yes
checking for atexit... yes
checking for basename... yes
checking for bcmp... yes
checking for bcopy... yes
checking for bsearch... yes
checking for bzero... yes
checking for calloc... yes
checking for clock... yes
checking for ffs... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for index... yes
checking for insque... yes
checking for memchr... yes
checking for memcmp... yes
checking for memcpy... yes
checking for memmem... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for mempcpy... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for mkstemps... yes
checking for putenv... yes
checking for random... yes
checking for rename... yes
checking for rindex... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for sigsetmask... yes
checking for stpcpy... yes
checking for stpncpy... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strndup... yes
checking for strnlen... yes
checking for strrchr... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for strtod... yes
checking for strtol... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for strverscmp... yes
checking for tmpnam... yes
checking for vasprintf... yes
checking for vfprintf... yes
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking for vsprintf... yes
checking for waitpid... yes
checking for setproctitle... no
checking whether alloca needs Cray hooks... no
checking stack direction for C alloca... -1
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for sys_errlist... yes
checking for sys_nerr... yes
checking for sys_siglist... yes
checking for external symbol _system_configuration... no
checking for __fsetlocking... yes
checking for canonicalize_file_name... yes
checking for dup3... yes
checking for getrlimit... yes
checking for getrusage... yes
checking for getsysinfo... no
checking for gettimeofday... (cached) yes
checking for on_exit... yes
checking for psignal... yes
checking for pstat_getdynamic... no
checking for pstat_getstatic... no
checking for realpath... yes
checking for setrlimit... yes
checking for sbrk... yes
checking for spawnve... no
checking for spawnvpe... no
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strsignal... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for sysctl... yes
checking for sysmp... no
checking for table... no
checking for times... yes
checking for wait3... yes
checking for wait4... yes
checking whether basename is declared... no
checking whether ffs is declared... yes
checking whether asprintf is declared... no
checking whether vasprintf is declared... no
checking whether snprintf is declared... yes
checking whether vsnprintf is declared... yes
checking whether calloc is declared... yes
checking whether getenv is declared... yes
checking whether getopt is declared... yes
checking whether malloc is declared... yes
checking whether realloc is declared... yes
checking whether sbrk is declared... yes
checking whether strverscmp is declared... no
checking whether canonicalize_file_name must be declared... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for getpagesize... (cached) yes
checking for working mmap... yes
checking for working strncmp... yes
configure: updating cache ./config.cache
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating testsuite/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing default commands
mkdir -p -- ./bfd
Configuring in ./bfd
configure: creating cache ./config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first
make[1]: *** [configure-bfd] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/binutils-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Didn't you delete the binutils-build after pass 1? You should always delete the work directories after finishing and use clean ones, especially with such sensitive packages that have several passes. Try to be more careful when you read the instructions. [Chapter 5.3](http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/generalinstructions.html)

Comment: @cylgalad The link is broken, you mean https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/partintro/generalinstructions.html ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the verbose build output the source directory is already configured and needs cleaning before binutils will build. You should run `make distclean` then re-attempt the build.